# Which of the two is a better for an implementation of binary search?

Tags: binary-search

In an array with low and high as indices of left and right boundaries , respectively, following are two ways of finding middle element:

```
1. int mid = (low+high)/2;
2. int mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);
```

Comment: That's not a binary search. that's a midpoint finder.

Comment: I changed my question. Sorry I missed a part.

Comment: The first one could overflow, so the second is better.

Comment: Can you elaborate, how the first implementation will overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first implementation will just cause overflow of the variable. Second one takes care of that.